# Ideals in $F[X]$ are of the form $(f(x))$ where $f$ can be chosen to be monic. How?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am reading a statement whereby it says that 
In $F[X]$, where $F$ is a field, any ideal is of the form $(f(x))$ where $f$ can be chosen to be monic.

I don't get this part of the statement '$f$ can be chosen to be monic'. If we have some non-monic polynomial that generates an ideal, how can we have a non-monic version that generates the same ideal?

Comment: If the leading coefficient of the generator $f$ is $a$, $a^{-1} f$ generates the same ideal (and is monic).

Comment: In any commutative ring $R$, where $u$ denotes some invertible element, $(a)=(ua)$ for any element $a$. In $F[x]$, you can make any nonzero polynomial monic by multiplying by a unit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that $(f(x))=f(x)F[x]=\lambda f(x)F(x)$ so take $\lambda$ the inverse of the leading coefficient of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)$ can be chosen monic because, for any nonzero $r \in F$, $r^{-1} f(x) \in (f(x))$, since $(f(x))$ is an *ideal* in $F[x]$.  Now take $r$ to be the leading coefficient of $f(x)$.  Then $r^{-1}f(x)$ is monic, and it is straightforward that $(r^{-1}f(x)) = (f(x))$, so we might as well take $f(x)$ monic to begin with.